# Javascript widget library

Tags: widget, javascript, jquery-widgets

I am looking for a javascript library which looks like  [this](http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday#module=Dashboard&action=embeddedIndex&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday&idDashboard=1), having multiple widgets on the dash board.

I am sure there is a library, because,I remember using it but can't remember the name and googling for few days didn't help..

Please help me find such a library.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application you linked (Piwik) likely implements the Dashboard and its Widgets by using jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/).

jQuery UI contains ready-made widgets, like Accordion, Autocomplete, Datepicker, etc. It also provides you with a framework for writing your own widgets. For more details on this facet, take a look at jQuery UI's Widget Factory (http://jqueryui.com/widget/).

For the dashboard part, you could try something like gridster.js (http://gridster.net/).